# Is this type of electrical connection up to US code?

Tags: electrical, wiring, code-compliance

While browsing ceiling lamps on Amazon, I came across [a product](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07DJ2TXNW) that seemed a little odd to me. More specifically, the install instructions, which contain this image:

[image: install instructions for the lamp]

Inside of this image, it shows that the lamp should be connected to power via adding on wire nuts or using a push-in connector between the body of the lamp and the wall. I thought in the USA such connections could only be done inside of a dedicated, insulated junction box.

Is this okay? Is the lamp somehow made of insulated material, or something?

Comment: Quite a few junction/fixture boxes are metal and not insulated, should be grounded though, but not all are.  Lamp does look like plastic.

Comment: Is it UL listed

Comment: From the amazon page, it doesn't appear to be UL listed. Not bueno.

Comment: There's not much point asking "up to code" questions, unless you state what country you're in.

Comment: Up to code for where in the world? There are so many different regs...

Comment: It's not a "push in" connector, it's one that locks onto the wire when you close the lever.  I've used these several times on stuff that purports to be "up to code" in the US.

Comment: '"N and L port", and the blue and brown wires visible in pictures 3-5, indicate this device was not designed to _USA_ electrical code standards.  It might be perfectly fine according to some other standard.

Comment: Those Wago "lever-nuts" are fine, but you really have to watch your sourcing on those. The mail-order space is flooded with overseas counterfeits.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Brown hot + blue neutral indicates it is *not intended* for the North American market, and most likely is not safe or certified, due to weirdnesses/annoyances in how mail order works.  (Not that there's anything wrong with gear properly accredited for the EU market).

The upshot is that Amazon "is eBay" these days... and any such site is a dangerous place to buy electrical gear.  *Here on DIY.SE we advise strongly against it.*

Case in point:

[image]

NOT sold by Amazon proper.  **This is a third-party seller**.  Amazon has a program called "Amazon Marketplace" where 3rd party sellers are allowed into Amazon, their listings commingle with Amazon's own, and they even ship from Amazon warehouses in Amazon boxes under "Amazon Fulfillment". Prime even works on them.

In fact, they are "the eBay crowd" who are largely shoveling cheap crud off Alibaba.  This stuff ignores all the civilized world's safety and quality regulations - they use flammable and toxic-smoke plastics, too-small wires, very cheap components so they are more likely to catch fire and fail early.  Every way a corner can be cut, they cut it.

To add insult to injury, they charge near domestic prices for the stuff (as that makes it seem more legit).

I'm not picking on China, and I'm not saying *every single* Marketplace (nor eBay, Banggood, Wish, DealExtreme) seller is selling cheap unsafe garbage.  *But is certainly the way to bet.*

### How do we identify good gear, then?

For decades, the US and other countries have had National Testing Labs - UL for America, CSA for Canada, BSI for Britain, TUV for Germany, etc. etc.  Due to GATT agreements, we cross-recognize our testing labs and they are now called **Nationally *Recognized* Testing Labs**, and there's an official list of those on the web.

So the simple litmus test of any item is  a "UL" circle mark. Or other NRTL equivalent. While the crud sellers ferociously spam "CE" on *everything* (along with CCC, FCC and RoHS, all marks with no consequence for them to fake), it is extremely rare for the crud sellers in the Amazon/eBay mail order junkstream to fake UL marks.  Also, any proper UL mark includes a nearby 6-8 digit File Number, and UL can confirm the File Number is legitimate.

Sometimes you do see a junkstream seller who has "gone legit" and gotten an actual, proper NRTL listing (Sonoff comes to mind). *And then, they very proudly make it the biggest mark*.  I have inspected these when they come up, and I am satisfied as to their legitimacy.  If CE or CCC is the biggest mark, they got nothin'.

Comment: Well, if you don't mind having to make a (free) account, the [UL Product iQ](https://iq.ulprospector.com) site is how you can confirm UL file numbers are legit.  CSA and ETL/Intertek have similar facilities on their websites, although neither of theirs require registration

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Yeah, I have a spreadsheet of all my accounts... started it about when I joined SE, it was over 100 then, now it's over 200.  *And I'm not even that social* (more "utility" accounts (toll tag, DMV) than social accounts (SE, FB).  Anyway it's out of hand and I am trying to quit lol.

Comment: There are lots of rip-offs that display a quality mark - that just isn't representative of the quality. It's been cribbed from a legit. So how are we to know?

Comment: There do appear to be markings on the back of the light (in the video), but it's of such poor resolution that I can't make out anything except IP44, RoHS and CE. Which tells us exactly nothing. Didn't recognize any testing laboratory among them. Somewhere around 0:47 in the video.

Comment: I didn't know newegg was not a retailer.  Thank you for that.

Comment: @jay613 Newegg hosts a lot of 3rd party stuff these days.  Since the founders sold out a few years ago, about the only thing special it has is the level of detail in some of it's part searches.  eg for PC mother boards.

Comment: @jay613 Removed. Please reconsider any DV.

Comment: @Tim As discussed, look for marks from NRTLs. In the junk stream seen on eBay, Amazon etc. I look at a lot of stuff, and virtually all of it has a giant CE or CCC and no other marks. There is no consequence for faking those, they are garbage marks (for us).  Some of them are using their profits to improve their product and get a bona-fide NRTL listing. When they do, they display their *earned* NRTL mark very proudly, and usually stop faking CE and CCC.

Comment: @Mast if they had a bona-fide UL listing, it would be the biggest mark by far.  The few that *have earned* an NRTL mark display it proudly and usually stop faking other marks. (no need). That means if CE/CCC is the biggest, it's positively junk.  (actual European-market products notwithstanding).

Comment: Digressing a bit, but: How would inserting another connection, this time in a box per U.S. standards, improve safety over a direct connection? As you can guess, I'm in Europe, specifically Germany.

Comment: @Peter not much... I don't see a splice issue here (and German specs are just as good as US specs anyway)... the problem with the above light is that nothing is known about how it is made: is it a fire hazard? Shock hazard? Flammability and toxic smoke from plastics and wire insulation?  Insulation performance in damp?  What we know is the builder chose to have zero accountability.

Comment: @Peter I mean even in the US some lights are approved to be served from a cable coming through a hole in drywall. The light provides the junction box.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica I can vividly imagine all those hazards but fail to see how another connection somewhere else would alleviate them (I think the U.S. solution consists of a connector box somewhere else, close by, from which "pigtails" run to the lamp; but don't you still need to attach those pigtails to the lamp?)

Comment: @Peter yeah, I don't think I'm saying that it would.  The splice here is the least of the problems.

Answer (score 4):

Those are lever locks and inside the lamp fixture itself.
In the U.S.there needs to be a box above the canopy of the electrical cover, in the U.K. I see photos on this site that do not have boxes so that may be legal there.

Part of the problem with purchasing things online is they may not be code compliant in the U.S. and frankly illegal to install but not to purchase and own.

When purchasing on line look for a UL , ETL, TUV or other 3rd party testing agency that is recognized, CE is not to mention one that is commonly purchased here and inspectors will red flag an inspection, in my hospital some coffee makers could not be used because of the same issue.

Comment: Aren't wire nuts illegal in the U.K.?  Just curious. +1

Comment: @JACK IIRC they were outlawed by the 14th edition wiring regulations in 1966.

Comment: ... which is sort of sad if you recall that the wire nut was invented by an expat Scot, William P. Marr.

Comment: I mentioned many UK ceiling fixture photos show connections without boxes usually screw terminals. Screw terminals are legal in the U.S. if listed, the same as lever locks, wire nuts and backstabs but they all require a box for the connection. They may be listed there is a stamp in the plastic but it cannot be read, just because it comes from china doesn’t mean it is not UL check most products do come from there.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate early wire nuts were bad even if used as per instructions.  The UK banned them vs the US allowing makers to update to better designs that can be used safely.

Comment: The Wago-style lever thingy looks perfectly fine from a European perspective. Where would you put a box, between lamp and ceiling or what? And then have two short wires going to the lever thingy?

Answer (score 1):

This may be up to code in some countries where wall and ceiling construction is solid brick or concrete, where wiring is installed according to code which anticipates this kind of installation, and if this fixture is approved for use in those countries.   A lot of ifs, and I deduce you are in a country where hollow wall wood construction is common and code requires metal junction boxes and UL-approved fixtures regardless of construction.

So: No.